# How to change minibuffer location in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

I'm tired to move my eye to minibuffer that is bottom of Emacs.
So I want to minimize eye movement. Is there any solution for this? I want something like as following.

- Setting minibuf location on top of current frame.(I don't know It's effective or not. )
- If I typed M-x, minibuf show up center of current frame.(I think it's effective.)

Answer (score 1):

I find it helps to have the minibuffer always in the same place on my screen --- IOW, a *standalone minibuffer frame*.  Yes, that involves eye movement, but always to the same place.  You might find that this helps.  See library [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el) for an implementation that is easy to try.